# Background Services In Xamarin Stop When App Is Terminated

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, background-task

can any one help me with the background services with XF, i had tried following the documentation, as i am able to run the activity when my app is in background but as soon as i terminate the app the background activity also gets terminated

Example - Whatsapp running in background even if we clear the app from running stack

Answer (score 0):

There are/was problem for me with background service and Google Analytics implementation (https://github.com/KSemenenko/GoogleAnalyticsForXamarinForms). Something with timers (repeaters), check your source/packages for Device.StartTimer usage, at background mode they must be stopped or background service will be terminated.